# i want to replace ‘ and ’ with ' in html using python. i tried multiple ways but failed

Tags: python, html, python-docx, pypandoc

I wrote a code that converts a Word document to HTML using pypandoc because I even want images in that. The problem is my docx file contains characters `‘` and `’` which turn into something different in HTML when sent as a mail body. I want `‘` and `’` to be replaced with `'`, a normal apostrophe.

Check the attached images so that the difference is clear enough.

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsLXk.png)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0BJS.png)

I tried a few ways as shown in the code below. I commented out ways which I tried but failed.

```py
# Read the HTML file
with open(html_file, 'r') as file:
    html_data = file.read()
            
    # Replace all occurrences of ',' with '
    # print("called")
    html_data = re.sub("‘", "'", html_data)
    html_data = re.sub("’", "'", html_data)
    # html_data = re.sub(r'’', "'", html_data)
    # html_data =  re.sub(r'‘', "'", html_data)
    # html_data = re.sub(r'“', '"', html_data)
    # html_data = re.sub(r'”', '"', html_data)
    # html_data = html_data.replace("‘", "'")
    # html_data = html_data.replace("’", "'")
    # html_data = html_data.replace('“', "'")
    # html_data = html_data.replace("”", "'")
```

For example, my Word document contains a phrase `i’d like to` that should get converted to `i'd like to`.

Comment: I don't know enough about this but you may be able to enforce some type of encoding on the string/object/document/file like UTF-8, latin1, etc that will fix weird characters

Comment: i tried it but didnt work

Comment: print the variable `html_data` to see if sub worked, It may be getting converted somewhere else

Comment: I tried that but is it now getting replaced in sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        # Read the HTML file
    with open(html_file, 'r') as file:
        html_data = file.read()
        
    # Replace all occurrences of ',' with '
    html_data = re.sub("‘", "'",html_data)
    html_data = re.sub("’", "'",html_data)
    html_data = re.sub("â€˜", "'",html_data)
    html_data = re.sub("â€™", "'",html_data)
```

Try this it works, in html ‘ is sometimes considered as â€˜ and ’ is considered as â€™ so it does not replaces using your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to escape the character so it does not conflict with `string` declaration:

```
s = 'i’d like to'
m = s.replace('’', '\'')
print(m)
```

Output:

```
"i'd like to"
```

Comment: This is not the issue the problem that's taking place is I am sending the html as mail body and there this turns into something else something like €.